# How to merge data from a scoreboard

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to double arrows their X Motion and it's working great except for the part that I can't apply the scoreboard data to the entities. My system is so build that it can handle multiple arrows at once but I get stuck in the last command

```
execute as @e[type=arrow] store result score @s Bullet.Y run data get entity @s Motion[1] 100000

execute as @e[type=arrow] run scoreboard players operation @s Bullet.X *= 2 F.Data

execute as @e[type=arrow] run data modify entity @s Motion[0] set from **score @s Bullet.X**
```

This is not a thing but it would be really handy to use. I just don't know how to do this with using a valid command.

Answer (score 1):

It's the same as your first command but in reverse:

```
/execute as @e[type=arrow] store result entity @s Motion[0] double <scale> run scoreboard players get @s Bullet.X
```